# R dplyr find all mutated rows

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to identify all rows of a tibble that have been altered after  `mutate` .
My real data has multiple columns and the `mutate` function changes more than one column at once.

```r
# library 
library(tidyverse)

# get df
df <- tibble(name=c("A","B","C","D"),value=c(1,2,3,4))

# mutate df
dfnew <- df %>% 
  mutate(value=case_when(name=="A" ~ value+1, TRUE ~value)) %>% 
  mutate(name=case_when(name=="B" ~ "K", TRUE ~name))
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Now I look for a way how to compare all rows of `df` with `dfnew` and identify all rows with at least one change.

The desired output would be:

```
# desired output:
# 
# # A tibble: 4 x 2
# name  value
# <chr> <dbl>
# 1 A         2
# 2 K         2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
anti_join(dfnew, df)

  name  value
  <chr> <dbl>
1 A         2
2 K         2
```

Answer (score 1):

@tmfmnk's response does the trick, but if you'd like to use a loop (e.g. for some flexibility using different kinds of messages or warnings depending on what you're checking) you could do:

```
output <- list()
for (i in 1:nrow(dfnew)) {
  if (all(df[i, ] == dfnew[i, ])) {
    next
  }
  output[[i]] <-  dfnew[i, ]
}
bind_rows(output)

# A tibble: 2 x 2
  name  value
  <chr> <dbl>
1 A         2
2 K         2
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also use `setdiff` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
setdiff(dfnew, df)
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#  name  value   
#  <chr> <dbl>
#1 A         2
#2 K         2
```

---

Or using `fsetdiff` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
fsetdiff(setDT(dfnew), setDT(df))
```